# Convert a 24 bit in memory image to indexed color

Tags: .net, gdi+, system.drawing

I have an image that I have created in memory as Format24bppRgb.

I save this as a PNG and it is 24kb.

If I save the same image with photoshop as a 24bit PNG it comes to about the same size, but if i save it as an 8bit PNG with only 32 colors it goes down to 5kb.

How can I create an indexed version of a PNG file using C# / GDI+ / System.Drawing ?

I'm having a hard time finding any answers to this question that don't just apply to grayscale images or require an external library. is it not possible within GDI+ as is?

Answer (score 2):

I ended up using the [FreeImageAPI DLL](http://freeimage.sourceforge.net/), with a C# wrapper. I try to avoid 3rd party libraries but I don't think there is any other choice. It seems a pretty standard and well used library.

In my case I have an `System.Drawing.Image` object `'image'` that was dynamically created - which I want to save to the HttpContext output stream as a compressed image. Note that `Image` does not have the needed `GetHbitmap()` method, but `Bitmap` does.

```
// convert image to a 'FreeImageAPI' image
var fiBitmap = FreeImageAPI.FreeImageBitmap.FromHbitmap((image as Bitmap).GetHbitmap());
fiBitmap.ConvertColorDepth(FreeImageAPI.FREE_IMAGE_COLOR_DEPTH.FICD_08_BPP);

// see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/582766
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
fiBitmap.Save(ms, FreeImageAPI.FREE_IMAGE_FORMAT.FIF_PNG, FreeImageAPI.FREE_IMAGE_SAVE_FLAGS.PNG_Z_BEST_COMPRESSION);
context.HttpContext.Response.OutputStream.Write(ms.ToArray(), 0, (int)ms.Length);
```

My 24kb bitmap is now only 9kb :-)

**Tip:** Be sure to have both 'FreeImageNET' AND 'FreeImage' dlls available in your bin when you run it. At the current time the C# sample projects contain a reference to 'Library.DLL' which doesn't seem to exist in their zip file. Using `FreeImageNET.dll` and `FreeImage.dll` works though. You'll get an annoying file not found error if you don't realize that `FreeImageNet` != `FreeImage` !

Comment: How to install it on windows 7 64 bit ?

Comment: Be careful with bitmap.GetHbitmap(). You have to free that memory manually or it'll leak. 1. [DllImport("gdi32.dll")] private static extern bool DeleteObject(IntPtr hObject); 2. IntPtr hBitmap = bitmap.GetHbitmap(); 3. FreeImageBitmap freeImageBitmap = FreeImageBitmap.FromHbitmap(hBitmap); 4. (do stuff) 5. DeleteObject(hBitmap);

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with **nQuant** (which you can install with nuget, or see references below). The following example converts an image on disk and would be readily adapted to meet your needs.

```
    public static bool TryNQuantify(string inputFilename, string outputFilename)
    {
        var quantizer = new nQuant.WuQuantizer();
        var bitmap = new Bitmap(inputFilename);
        if (bitmap.PixelFormat != System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb)
        {
            ConvertTo32bppAndDisposeOriginal(ref bitmap);
        }

        try
        {
            using (var quantized = quantizer.QuantizeImage(bitmap))
            {
                quantized.Save(outputFilename, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
        finally
        {
            bitmap.Dispose();
        }
        return true;
    }

    private static void ConvertTo32bppAndDisposeOriginal(ref Bitmap img)
    {
        var bmp = new Bitmap(img.Width, img.Height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
        using (var gr = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
            gr.DrawImage(img, new Rectangle(0, 0, img.Width, img.Height));
        img.Dispose();
        img = bmp;
    }
```

For more information see:

- http://nquant.codeplex.com/
- https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Convert-32-bit-PNGs-to-81ef8c81

Comment: This is good if you want an alpha channel that isn't a 1 bit channel. You get get an 8 bit image with alpha similar to what tinypng.com gives you. But be warned it is quite slow

Comment: This worked fine to me, however it's important to note that when I dealt with images that had height bigger than 4550 pixels it failed to generate image and the output was an empty gray image.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to convert 16777216 colors down to 32.  This is a non-trivial problem, and there are many ways to do it, all of which have their plusses and minuses. It's not something you often need to do, especially since full color displays became ubiquitous.

This Microsoft article has some information about GIF files that should be relevant to PNG also.

http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;Q319061

Comment: but Photoshop makes it look so easy :-) i'm looking at FreeImage.NET right now

Comment: Or the image may have 32 colors anyway in which case you don't loose anything.