# Dispose image and memory stream objects after calling HttpContext.Response.OutputStream.Write()

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, image-processing

How to improve the code below in terms of better performance?
For example, must I explicitly dispose both `MemoryStream` and `Image` objects after calling `OutputStream.Write()`?

Any improvement on other areas, e.g. `Buffer` and `MemoryStream` allocation?

The code is to allow a web user to download a PNG file. Part of it is below:

```
OutputImage(image);
image.Dispose();
...

public void OutputImage(Image image){
    using(MemoryStream temp = new MemoryStream()){
       image.Save(temp, ImageFormat.Png)
       byte[] buffer = temp.GetBuffer();
       context.Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, temp.Length);              
    }
}
```

ASP.NET, .NET 4.5

[Response.OutputStream GetBuffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582766/cannot-render-image-to-httpcontext-response-outputstream)

[Response.OutputStream MemoryStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5629251/c-sharp-outputting-image-to-response-output-stream-giving-gdi-error)

[MemoryStream](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/5884995d-23ac-4fd9-bae3-878b0da70f76/storing-and-retrieving-image-to-memorystream-as-byte-arrays-a-generic-error-occurred-in-gdi?forum=csharpgeneral)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uses of "using" in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75401/uses-of-using-in-c-sharp)

Comment: It is much more than that.

Comment: The general rule is that you must dispose of all disposable objects, unless you **explicitly know** you don't need to.